# Synced Video and Powerpoint Slides Side by Side

Tags: video, sync, flash, microsoft-powerpoint, youtube

I would like to take a video of a lecture and display it on a website with the slides from the presentation displaying next to the video. The slides would switch according to how they were switched by the presenter. In other words, the video and the slide display are syncronized.

The three websites that provide this service are:

1. [Zentation](http://www.zentation.com/viewer/index.php?passcode=HVbjvbZxuv)
2. VCasmo
3. KNoodle

But I would like to do it (and host it) myself with Flash, HTML5, Javascript, etc. Has anyone implemented something like that themselves?

I posted this question incorrectly [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907052/lecture-capture-implementation-synced-video-and-slides-side-by-side).

Comment: I hate to say that but if you'd like to do it in Flash, HTML5 and JavaScript you were right with StackOverflow all along :) The only difference is that **here** you said you'd do it yourself and on SO you asked what others did. I'd suggest editing your question on SO and removing it here.

Comment: I realize you're looking to build it manually, but it might worth your time looking into Adobe Presenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a basic demo on Slidecasting, syncing slides with audio - http://code.narendrasisodiya.com/slidecast/demo-slidecasting.html

Comment: Very interesting solution.